# How to clone div content and append only one at the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have form that should allow user to click on the Add Row and create another identical row. This will required `new row` to give an option to the user to delete that row if created accidentally. Here is my code that doesn't works correct. After I click on add row second time code will insert another 3 rows. Somethings odd is going on with the way I insert and clone new rows.

```js
$("#add_row").on('click', addRow);
function addRow() {
    $(".data-bug-item").clone().insertAfter(".data-bug-item");
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="dataBug" class="bug-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn" name="add_row" id="add_row">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Row
                                                    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required data-bug-item">
    <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="frm_column" id="frm_column" required>
          <option value="">--Choose--</option>
          <option value="1">Location</option>
          <option value="2">Name</option>
          <option value="3">Year</option>
          <option value="4">City</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr" id="frm_descr" placeholder="Enter Description" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to see only one row at the time and button on the end of the Description input field for Delete.

Comment: `$(".data-bug-item").clone().insertAfter(".data-bug-item");` finds **all** elements in the document that match that class, it then clones all of them, and then inserts all of them.  If you only want one, only select one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that, it's to clone a minor part of html.

You're cloning everything including the cloned part.

After `data-bug-item` create a div with same name just to identify and clone JUST the form and not all informations inside the div.

Example:

```js
$("#add_row").on('click', addRow);
function addRow() {
    $("#form-data-bug-item").clone().insertAfter(".data-bug-item");
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="dataBug" class="bug-section">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <button type="button" class="btn" name="add_row" id="add_row">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Row
             </button>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required data-bug-item">
  <div id="form-data-bug-item">
  <label class="control-label" for="type"><span class="label label-default">Column & Description:</span></label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
   <select class="form-control" name="frm_column" id="frm_column" required>
     <option value="">--Choose--</option>
     <option value="1">Location</option>
     <option value="2">Name</option>
     <option value="3">Year</option>
     <option value="4">City</option>
   </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="frm_descr" id="frm_descr" placeholder="Enter Description" required>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you just need to clone form-data-bug-item

PS: I'm not considering another things on your code, just the solution.

Comment: That works but I just realized each cloned set needs to update `id's` as well. We can not have same id twice on the same page.

Comment: What ID are you saying? You can change to `name` or something else you want. To search use `$("input[name='NAME']").clone`